How to get collection of abstract class - table using Table-per-concrete-type configuration?
I've created a database (SQLite) with tables by TPC strategy, so one abstract class and several others derived from it. In my application I would to get all elements with by some field implemented in the abstract class (for example Name). Problem is that each derived class has his own DbSet<> field in my class derived from DbContext, and I don't know yet how to go through all items without taking some special collection or concating all into a one IEnumerable.
Entity:
public abstract class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string EducationLevel { get; set; }
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string FavoriteToy { get; set; }
}

Context:
public class MainDbContext : DbContext
{
 public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>().UseTpcMappingStrategy();
 }
}

How to gen all animals Animal where Name can be a 'Bob' for example?

Add an DbSet<Animal> Animals property as well and query that, eg context.Animals.Where(a=>a.Name=="Bob").

Thank you, it works for me. I just thought for some reason that for TPC strategy should not be DbSet with the base, abstract class, my fault.

DbSet specifies the entities in the model, not the tables. To query something, it must either be a DbSet property or you must use the .Set<T>() method, eg context.Set<Animals>().Where(a=>a.Name=="Bob"). The downside with the method is that the entity initialization is delayed until the first call to Set<>

Queries must always start from an You can add the type as an entity with :
public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

and use it in the query
var animals=context.Animals.Where(a=>a.Name=="Bob").ToList();

or use the DbContext.Set method :
var animals=context.Set<Animal>().Where(a=>a.Name=="Bob").ToList();

The property is more convenient if you need to query Animals frequently.
